# Apache/Docusign - Restrict location by host or ip

Tags: apache, docusignapi

I'm trying to restrict an url called by Docusign event when a document is completed.
I want to only give access to this url by Docusign host or ip but i'm unable to do so because of my limited skills on Apache.
By following this documentation https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature

I've tried to add this line in my vhost :

```
    <LocationMatch "^/souscription/api/[^/].*/callback/.*$">
        Require host docusign.com docusign.net
    </LocationMatch>
```

But I have this error in apache log:

```
[Wed Jul 29 12:59:09.663648 2020] [authz_host:error] [pid 32671] [client 162.248.186.11:50836] AH01753: access check of 'docusign.com docusign.net' to /souscription/api/1.0/callback/118/completed failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
```

What's wrong with my config ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your questions. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For Apache questions, use [superuser.com](/https://superuser.com/)
- When building a listening server for receiving DocuSign webhook messages, filtering by IP is **not recommended** since it leads to a brittle installation that can fail at exactly the wrong time. Instead:

1. Use the combination of the Basic Authentication and HMAC features to assure yourself that the message really came from DocuSign.
2. Or better, use an intermediate PaaS service to queue the notification messages. The additional feature is that you can receive the notification messages from behind your firewall with no changes to the firewall. See the [example repo](https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-aws) and associated blog posts.

Comment: Finally, i'm using hmac security as you advise https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect-hmac